# JDOM 2 Get position and index of a specific XML element

Tags: java, xml, jdom, jdom-2

I have an XML document and I want to add an element in a specific position (index) using the name and attribute of existing element, So I have to find the index of this specific element.

Example:

```
<root org="667">
<myobject name="Propert1">KS7799</p>
<myobject name="Propert2">88YSJJ</p>
<myobject name="Propert3">KKQ87</p>
<myobject name="Propert4">122ZKK</p>
<myobject name="Propert5">LQLX9</p>
<myobject name="Propert6">LLQS8</p> // I want to get index of this element
<myobject name="Propert7">LLLX9</p>
<myobject name="Propert8">LLSSKNX9</p>
<myobject name="Propert9">MQLKSQ9</p>
<myobject name="Propert10">MLKLKQSQ9</p>
</root>
```

My code:

```
 for (Element ObjectElement : Dataelement.getChildren("myobject")) {


                Attribute nameattr_class = ObjectElement.getAttribute("name");


                if (nameattr_class.getValue().equals("Propert6")) {

                   // I want to index of this element
                }


      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the element you want to insert after, there are a few things you can do....

You can get an Iterator on the collection, and just add the element.... like:

```
Element toinsert = new Element("toinsert");

Iterator<Element> it = Dataelement.getChildren("myobject");
while (it.hasNext() && !"Propert6".equals(it.next().getAttribute("name"))) {
    // advance the iterator.
}
it.add(toinsert);
```

Alternatively, you can find the Element with the right property using, for example, an XPath.....

```
XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.instance();
XPath<Element> xp = xpf.compile("//myobject[@name='propert6']", Filters.element());
Element propert6 = xp.evaluateFirst(Dataelement);

Element toinsert = new Element("toinsert");
Element parent = toinsert.getParent();
parent.addContent(parent.indexOf(propert6), toinsert);
```